# How to rotate a sprite without rotating the object or make movement rotation independant

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, unity3d-2dtools

I have made a thing in unity2d where an object moves according to the location of the mouse compared to the location of the object, to do this there is a vector going from the object to the mouse, all movement is either parrallel to this or perpendicular to it.

This worked fine before adding rotation of the sprite (added as shown below)

```
void RoterModMus()
{
    fRotationIGrader = Vector2.Angle (Vector2.up,  vVectorToMouse.normalized);
    if(vVectorToMouse.normalized.x<0)
    {
        transform.rotation =Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, fRotationIGrader);
    }
    else{transform.rotation =Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -fRotationIGrader); }
}
```

When i stop running this funtion in update the movement works again.

Is there a way to either rotate the sprite without rotating the object, or to make this not hurt movement??

I havn't been able to find anything on any of those questions, and i cant figure it out (sorry for danish code)

The code checks the angle between up and the mouse (up is zero in unity) and sets the rotation of the object to that or minus that
Awwkaw

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add an empty gameObject with the sprite component as a child to your object and then rotate the child AKA empty gameObject with sprite.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!

Edit:

but wont i have to do all collision detecting from the sprite placeholderobject now?

also what causes that the original didn't work?

Comment: You could add rigidbody (for collision detection) on the same gameObject as the sprite. Why is it you don't want to rotate the object itself? 
Not sure why it's not working, but looking at the script I fail to see anything suggesting rotation of a single component/object. It seems as if you are trying to rotate the entire object that you are also trying to move. Rotating the object and moving it along a straight line is probably what's hurting movement.

Comment: when i try to rotate the object itself the movement for some reason doesn't work, i think it rotates the direction of the vector that detemines where the mouse are( i don't know what else it could be) even if i rotate before detemening that vector

Comment: How about countering the objectRotation by subtracting the angle from the vector? I.e. if you rotate the object 45 degrees, subtract 45 degrees so you end up at zero again. That way the vector always points towards the same point.

Comment: i'll try that, but then why do i have to do this when i never change the vector to begin with (i just suspect that unity does)

Comment: I must admit I have problems visualising what you are trying to do, but the code you wrote in your post _does_ rotate the object. Depending on how you have defined your vector -- it may also rotate. Atleast, that's how I interpret it.

Comment: the problem was when i instead of just rotating the object also moved it by translating it's transform, but your idea worked